# How can I achieve: If first 3 decimals of my number are 0 then number = 0 in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

If first 3 decimals of my number are 0 and number starts with 0, then number = 0:

Example:

n=0.0005677=> n= 0(0.00)

n=0.000055664=> n= 0(0.00)

**Edit 1:**

Here is a sample:

```
WHERE   ((cc.ID = @ID) OR (@ID IS NULL))
    AND ((cc.carTypeID = @CarTypeID) OR (@CarTypeID IS NULL))
    AND cc.active = 1
    AND lp.Latitude != 0 AND lp.Longitude != 0
```

Line 4 : So in this stored procedure it will not display the rows where latitude=0 and longitude =0 , i want to achieve the same thing when lat and longitude are for example 0.000455 or 0.0000555.

P.S.: Hope this makes it clear and sorry for the poor info when I first posted. Thanks all for your answers.

**Edit 2:**

What do you think about this approach? :

```
WHERE   ((cc.ID = @ID) OR (@ID IS NULL))
    AND ((cc.carTypeID = @CarTypeID) OR (@CarTypeID IS NULL))
    AND cc.active = 1
    AND CONVERT(NUMERIC(6, 3), lp.Latitude) !=0 AND CONVERT(NUMERIC(6, 3), lp.Longitude)  !=0
```

This function looks like is working as expected and can be used as a more general approach.

Do you know any downside or why I should I not use it?

Comment: So you want to round to 2 decimal places?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask].

Comment: Please check the edit I made.

Comment: I don't understand the question, what are you trying to achieve and how is it not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @n < 0.001 THEN 0 ELSE @n END
```

Any number that is less than `0.001` has `0` as integer part, and its decimal part starts with `000`.

You can replace `@n` with `ABS(@n)` if you want negative numbers handled the same way.

**EDIT:**

You formulate the `WHERE` clause of your query as:

```
WHERE ((cc.ID = @ID) OR (@ID IS NULL))
      AND ((cc.carTypeID = @CarTypeID) OR (@CarTypeID IS NULL))
      AND cc.active = 1
      AND lp.Latitude  >= 0.001 
      AND lp.Longitude >= 0.001
```

The above will *not* select a `Latitude`, or `Longitude`, value of `0.000455`, but it *will* select a value of `0.00455`.

Comment: Don't forget small negative numbers.

Comment: `ABS(@n)` can be used in this case, but I'm not sure what the OP wants in this case.

Comment: Was hoping to find a more general function and not hardcode the exact value.Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: You can create a UDF in this case, but using it may impact performance.

Comment: Please check my last edit, what do you think? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has a [`ROUND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) function you can use, but I'm guessing that's not what you are after. 
I think you need something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ABS(MyNumericValue) < 0.01 THEN 0.00 ELSE MyNumericValue END
FROM MyTable
```

using the [`ABS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189800.aspx) function will also take care of negative numbers (if you have any)